# How to control placement of control in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to control the placement of a generated control in asp .net 2.0 (c#)?

So for example in my page_load I create a new Panel() and then do Form.Controls.Add(pnl). However I'm finding it renders right at the end of the form.

I would like it rendering as the first element in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**[Controls.AddAt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.addat.aspx)** method, which adds the specified Control object to the collection at the specified index location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as54k8b6(VS.71).aspx) control?